# AskUbuntu: how do I filter in questions which have both tag1 and tag2?

Tags: discussion, tags

For example, what if I want to see questions that have both tags: graphics and drivers. How do I do that?

Or, how do I see only posts that have the "graphics" tag, "drivers" tag, and have an answer?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A query like the following should work:

```
[graphics] [drivers] answers:1
```

<sup><sub>(I get about 500+ results.)</sub></sup>
For more search options, check out [the help page on searching](https://askubuntu.com/help/searching).